# Whats the best way to find text after a certain point

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an Excel column called " Asset Name" I am have values like

```
LDNWSW-LXP17KZ
ADFHGW-WXP17KZ
ASDWSW-DXP17KZ
```

I need a formula to get the first character right of the hyphen for each value in 
another column. The hyphen may occur in **any** position (except first).

Any pointers? Thanks in Advance

I have tried the formula `=RIGHT([AssetName],LEN([AssetName])-SEARCH("-",[AssetName]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the input, you have data column `AssetName` in Table, so this formula:

```
=MID([AssetName],FIND("-",[AssetName])+1,1)
```

Should do the job for you. Type it in any column of the Table and better store it as `Calculated Column` - Excel will suggest you to do so if you enter formula in Table column.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(D6,FIND("-",D6)),1)
```

where data is in D6

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this;

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,1)
```

The `FIND` function returns the position of the "-" within `A1` and the `MID` function returns the characters from a specified starting position, which in this case is the hyphen.